# hacer un if else correcto en procedure MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, json

tengo una condicion que se ejecutara dependiendo del dato que se le esta enviando al procedure.
este es mi codigo:

```
CREATE DEFINER = erp@localhost PROCEDURE sp_stockProductoMovimientoAlmacen(
    idProducto VARCHAR(50),
    operacion CHAR(6),
    cantidad INT,
    sucursal INT(2)
)
BEGIN
    IF operacion = 'suma' THEN
        UPDATE productoStockMedida psm INNER JOIN producto p ON p.id_producto = psm.id_producto SET psm.stock = psm.stock + (cantidad) WHERE p.id_producto = id_producto AND p.id_tipo_almacen = sucursal;
    ELSE IF operacion = 'resta' THEN
        UPDATE productoStockMedida psm INNER JOIN producto p ON p.id_producto = psm.id_producto SET psm.stock = psm.stock - (cantidad) WHERE p.id_producto = id_producto AND p.id_tipo_almacen = sucursal;
    ELSE
        /* ESCRIBO ESTE QUERY POR TEMA DE SINTAXIS DEL CASE WHEN, ESTE QUERY NO AFECTARA AL STOCK DE NINFUN PRODUCTO */
        UPDATE producto SET stock = stock - (cantidad) WHERE id_producto = '000000' AND id_tipo_almacen='000000';
    END IF;
END
```

este es el mensaje de error que me indica el MYSQL

## 1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' en la linea 9

Comment: porque el cambo :     cantidad INT,, no tiene espacio de memoria? quiza ese sea tu error

Comment: algo asi  : cantidad INT(20)

Answer (score 1):

Intenta corregir el ELSE IF, debe ir pegado no separado ELSEIF, es lo único que puedo notar en tu código. Espero te funcione, quedo atento.

Answer (score 0):

corregir el elseif va junto todo no va separado por eso te da error, el procedimiento quedaria de la siguiente manera

```
CREATE DEFINER = erp@localhost PROCEDURE sp_stockProductoMovimientoAlmacen(
    idProducto VARCHAR(50),
    operacion CHAR(6),
    cantidad INT,
    sucursal INT(2)
)
BEGIN
IF operacion = 'suma' THEN
        UPDATE productoStockMedida psm INNER JOIN producto p ON p.id_producto = psm.id_producto SET psm.stock = psm.stock + (cantidad) WHERE p.id_producto = id_producto AND p.id_tipo_almacen = sucursal;
ELSEIF operacion = 'resta' THEN
        UPDATE productoStockMedida psm INNER JOIN producto p ON p.id_producto = psm.id_producto SET psm.stock = psm.stock - (cantidad) WHERE p.id_producto = id_producto AND p.id_tipo_almacen = sucursal;
    ELSE
        /* ESCRIBO ESTE QUERY POR TEMA DE SINTAXIS DEL CASE WHEN, ESTE QUERY NO AFECTARA AL STOCK DE NINFUN PRODUCTO */
        UPDATE producto SET stock = stock - (cantidad) WHERE id_producto = '000000' AND id_tipo_almacen='000000';
    END IF;
END
```